# Images and Panels

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I'm having a problem adding a `JPanel` on top of an `Image`. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Image bgImage = loadImage(filename);
JPanel jp = new JPanel();

jp.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
jp.setOpaque(true);
jp.setBackgroudColor(Color.red);

bgImage.add(jp);
```

After doing this, I only see the `bgImage`. I tried everything but I still can't show the panel. Can somebody help me?

Comment: There is a typo in `setBackgroundcolor`.

Comment: There is no method named `setBackgroundColor` on `JPanel` anyway :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot place a component inside an `Image`. What you want to do is paint the `Image` onto the background of a swing component (like `JPanel`). All swing components have a `paint()` method that calls these three methods (perhaps not quite this order): `paintComponent()`, `paintChildren()`, `paintBorder()`. So, you want to override the `paintComponent()` method to paint your background image over the panel. When this runs, your custom method will be called, and then the `paintChildren()` method will be called, which will paint all "child" components over the top of your background image:

```
class BackgroundImagePanel extends JPanel {

    public void setBackgroundImage(Image backgroundImage) {
        this.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        graphics.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    private Image backgroundImage;
}

BackgroundImagePanel panel = new BackgroundImagePanel();
panel.setBackgroundImage(image);
panel.add(new JTextField("Enter text here..."));
panel.add(new JButton("Press Me"));
```

Comment: uhm, sorry if my code is such a trash. i have a longer code that's working (not the one on top). But i really need to place the panel on top of the image, because from there i will be placing swing components...simply put, i want an Image as my background, an 'invisible' panel on top, and swing components last. :|

Comment: OK, understood. I have edited my answer to be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

The "BackgroundImagePanel" solution paints the image at its actual size. If this is a requirement, then you can just use a JLabel instead of creating a custom component.

The [BackgroundPanel](http://www.camick.com/java/blog.html?name=background-panel) entry shows how you can do this. It also provides a background panel with more custom image painting solutions, that will allow you to scale and tile the image, if this is part of your requirement.